# Correct way to transform python request parameters

Tags: python

I'm using Pyramid web framework to build a web app.  There are many times that I find myself doing this:

```
result = request.params.get('abc', None)
if result:
  result = simplejson.loads(result)
else:
  result = {}
```

The thing is, sometimes, 'abc' request parameter is not present and the value of  "result" would be None.  Hence I always have to check if it's None before I perform a `simplejson.loads` operation or else I would get a `TypeError: expected string or buffer` exception.

Is there a better/more "pythonic" way of doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
result = simplejson.loads(request.params.get('abc', '{}'))
```

Comment: Brilliant! Thanks.  Sorry I can only accept the answer in another 7 minutes.